# How to delete copies of character from string using regex?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I want to delete copies of 'i' in this example, tried using groups but it's not working. Where am I doing this wrong?

```
import re

a = '123iiii'
b = re.match('.*i(i+)', a)
print(b.group(1))
>>> i
a = re.sub(b.group(1), '', a)
print(a)
>>> 123
```

Desired result is '123i'.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you want just to leave one of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by simply using the `sub` function to replace a sequence of `i's` with a single `i`

```
import re

a = '123iiii'
a = re.sub(r'i+', 'i', a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that what you need is:

```py
import re

a = '123iiii'
a = re.sub(r"i+", "i", a)

print(a)
>>> 123i
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
([^i]*i)i*([^\r\n]*)
```

and a replacement of,

```
\1\2
```

might be OK to look into.

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
123iiii
123iiiiabc
123i
'''

expression = r'([^i]*i)i*([^\r\n]*)'

print(re.sub(expression, r'\1\2', string))
```

#### Output

```
123i
123iabc
123i
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HAKY7P/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/HAKY7P/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following will work even if you have the **i**'s in multiple places in the string.

```py
import re

s = '123iiii657iii'
re.sub('i+','i',s)
```

**Output**:

```
'123i675i'
```